# SQL Server: Sum of Unique values for multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server, I have a table as shown in the sample table below. I need to have sum of all the unique values per the columns "BookOrder, StationaryOrder, and Printing Order".

SAMPLE TABLE:

```
KeyIDCustomer   BooksOrder  StationaryOrder PrintingOrder
29945843         1070756    1891514            198876
29945843         1070756    1893827            198876
29945843         1070758    1891514            198876
29945843         1070758    1893827            198876
```

I am using the below coding to achieve this goal.

```
Select DISTINCT KeyIDCustomerID,
Sum(Case when BooksOrder is not null then 1 else 0 End) TotalBookOrders,  
Sum(Case when StationaryOrder is not null then 1 else 0 End) TotalStationaryOrder,
Sum(Case when PrintingOrder is not null then 1 else 0 End)TotalPrintingOrder
```

With this coding in am getting the results as below

```
  KeyIDCustomerID   TotalBookOrders TotalStationaryOrder    TotalPrintingOrder
   29945843                    4                       4                    4
```

I expect the results to be like this

```
  KeyIDCustomerID   TotalBookOrders TotalStationaryOrder    TotalPrintingOrder
   29945843                    2                       2                    1
```

Is there a way i can accomplish this Goal in SQL?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that only a half SELECT?

Comment: Make 3 queries instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a `group by`, `count(distinct column)` to count:

```
Select KeyIDCustomerID,
       COUNT(distinct BooksOrder) TotalBookOrders,  
       COUNT(distinct StationaryOrder) TotalStationaryOrder,
       COUNT(distinct PrintingOrder) TotalPrintingOrder
from tablename
group by KeyIDCustomerID
```

Comment: This is perfect.. Working for me. Thanks for the Quick help

Answer (score 5):

i think the proper term for

> sum of all the unique values per the columns

is "count of unique values"

`COUNT (DISTINCT column_name)` returns the number of unique, non-null values in column_name

```
Select 
KeyIDCustomerID,
COUNT(DISTINCT BooksOrder) as TotalBookOrders,  
COUNT(DISTINCT StationaryOrder) as TotalStationaryOrder,
COUNT(DISTINCT PrintingOrder) as TotalPrintingOrder
FROM SAMPLE_TABLE
GROUP BY KeyIDCustomerID
```